# Numeric Solution for 1-D ODE with only Neumann conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I tried to solve a simple ODE with only Neumann conditions like
[image]
But obviously this doesn't work.
I must add a useless DirichletCondition to make it work
[image]
I have verified that the solution is correct, but how can I get it without 
including the useless condition?

The code is

```
Sol = NDSolveValue[{Piecewise[{{1, x < 0}, {2.25, x > 0}}, 0]*u[x] + 
 Derivative[2][u][x] == 
     NeumannValue[I*(2*E^(I*x) - u[x]), x == -4*Pi] + 
 NeumannValue[(0. - 1.5*I)*u[x], x == 4*Pi], 
   DirichletCondition[1, False]}, u, {x, -4*Pi, 4*Pi}]
ReImPlot[Sol[x], {x, -4*Pi, 4*Pi}]
```

Comment: With only Neumann conditions, the solution is determined only up to a constant.  one way or another, the constant must be specified to obtain a numerical solution.

Comment: Maybe not, because if I add some useless condition like DirichletCondition[1, False], the program would find the correct solution.

Comment: @ZhuoJiahui I received this message in version 12 `NDSolveValue::fembpw: The boundary condition {DirichletCondition[1,False]} cannot be parsed and will be ignored.`

Comment: Yeee, that condition will be ignored but the solution is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to specify the method in this case, as otherwise `NDSolve` will first try to solve this as a time ODE:

```
Sol = NDSolveValue[{Piecewise[{{1, x < 0}, {2.25, x > 0}}, 0]*u[x] + 
     Derivative[2][u][x] == 
    NeumannValue[I*(2*E^(I*x) - u[x]), x == -4*Pi] + 
     NeumannValue[(0. - 1.5*I)*u[x], x == 4*Pi]}, u, {x, -4*Pi, 4*Pi},
   Method -> "FiniteElement"]
```

The fact that you 'only' have `NeuamnnValues` is not a problem here as they are *generalized* Neumann conditions (Robin conditions). Using only `NeumannValue` is only an issue if the `NeumannValue` is not a generalized `NeumannValue` (i.e. does not dependend on the dependent variable `u` in this case)